# speed optimization of the running total function

Tags: dax, powerpivot

There is a table with sales in units (qty) and revenue (rur) by products (SKU) and stores. The product in the table is aggregated into brands (this is a very simple example) .
the goal is to calculate for each cell of the PivotTable in the context of brands, extract the calculated price for 50% of the unit sales boundary in cumulative total (It's not a simple median for price!).

[image]

The rows in the example I deliberately ordered so that the estimated price (revenue "rur" divided by units "qty") was ordered in ascending order

[image]

Further, the units sales ordered by price are considered to be a cumulative total and are converted to a percentage of the total amount

[image]

After that, we look for the maximum percentage of shipments no more than the required border (50%) and return the price to the cell of the summary table for it[image]

visually, it looks like this

[image]

and the result in the table looks like this (in fact, we should not count 50% and the boundaries of 10% and 90% on a much larger table, but I'm simplifying here)

[image]

in the model, I created a calculated column

```
price:= [rur] / [qty]
```

and a measure that gives the necessary solution

```
price.50%qty=
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                'tbl',
                "cs.qty", SUMX ( FILTER ( 'tbl', tbl[price] <= EARLIER ( tbl[price] ) ), tbl[qty] )
            ),
            "cs.qty.%", [cs.qty] / SUM ( tbl[qty] )
        ),
        [cs.qty.%] <= 0.5
    ),
    [price]
)
```

it works on a small table of 1 cell but once the table of 20 brands is built for 10 months (200 cells) the result is impossible to wait. I know that EARLIER isn't optimal but I don't know how to optimize my function